# Native iOS Sencha 2 build - can we dynamically update the app

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Native iOS Sencha 2 build - can we dynamically update the app like we can when we download it from the web, or do we need to submit a new app to iTunes each time ?

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_packaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to push updates through iTunes, you can use a 3rd party service like: https://testflightapp.com/sdk/live/ to distribute your updates OTA